# SharePoint com MVC 5 qual melhor forma de trabalhar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Minha dúvida é qual forma de Hospedagem devo usar?

- Provider-hosted
- Autohosted
- SharePoint-hosted

Aplicação vai ficar no servidor para ser consumida pelos **usuários internos** e para **usuários externos**.

Nossa equipe é formada por desenvolvedores em **MVC** e tem uma pessoa de **Sharepoint**, qual padrão para usar MVC com Sharepoint nesta situação?

- Temos que fazer o usuário logar
- Precisamos ler lista do Sharepoint
- Vai existir workflow do Sharepoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando que a maior parte da equipe é de desenvolvedores em MVC, a melhor solução pode ser o Provider-hosted, uma vez que a arquitetura gira em torno de uma webapplication comum, que é integrada ao Sharepoint.

Desta forma, é possivel contar também com algumas facilidades como o SharePoint Client-Side Object Model (CSOM) ou  REST/OData APIs para acessar e gerenciar informações de dentro do Sharepoint.

Aqui vão alguns links que podem te ajudar nesta decisão:

Choose patterns for developing and hosting your SharePoint Add-in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx

SharePoint Add-ins
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx